# Error on Sequelize Post - Connection closed without response

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

New to sequelize. If I remove the {where: {username : uname}} it returns all of the records, but with it I get an error:

uname is being sent as paramter but the error log says username is not defined. Username is a field in the database.

```
// Find a single User with a username
export function findOne(req, res) {
    
    const uname = req.params.username;

    Users.findAll({where: {username : uname}})
        .then(data => {
            res.send(data);
        })
        .catch(() => {
            res.status(500).send({
                message: 'Error retrieving User with username=' + uname
            });
        });
}
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

User model:

```
import pkg from 'sequelize';
const { DataTypes } = pkg;

export default (sequelize) => {
    const User = sequelize.define('user', {
        title: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        firstname: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        lastname: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        username: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        password: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        email: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        }
    });
        
    return User;
};
```

Route:

```
import { findOne } from '../controllers/userlogin.controller.js';
import express from 'express';

export default app => {

    const router = express.Router();

// Find by User
router.post('/', findOne);

app.use('/api/userlogin', router);
};
```

Comment: Can you show a little more code like your User model and the route code?

Comment: `req.params.username`... you don't have any route parameters defined?

Comment: Just worked it out. It should be req.body.username..... so simple. Thanks